# Pandas - Join Data Frame - Value Error - But my column datatypes match

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to join two dataframes on a primary key.

```
master_characteristics_data = master_characteristics_data.join(all_cs_meter_runs,on='METER_NUMBER', lsuffix='_fl', rsuffix='_cs')
```

But I receive the error:

```
     File "C:\Users\cmorris\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\Python 3.6 - Server Version\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 986, in _maybe_coerce_merge_keys
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

However when I print the column data types I have no int64 columns:

```
print(master_characteristics_data.dtypes)
print(all_cs_meter_runs.dtypes)
```

They're all listed as type "object." I do not understand why pandas is receiving a type of int64 from one of the columns.

Comment: can you provide a small data sample?